# How to justify: Proof by contradiction ? (First Order Logic)

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic, proof-theory, provability

How to justify this rule?

> Proof by contradiction:
>   If a proof of $\Gamma,\lnot B\vdash C\land\lnot C$ involves no application of Gen using a variable free in $B$, then $\Gamma\vdash B.$

I did one proof using :

$B,\lnot C\vdash\lnot(B\to C)$, deduction theorem and lemma 1.11 by Mendelson [ [page 31](https://books.google.it/books?id=FS-sCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA31) ].

However I think the proof it's wrong because I didn't use the hypothesis 'involves no application of Gen using a variable free in $B$.'

Can someone help me to solve this problem please ??

---

**Edit:**

The proof that I did, and that I think it's pretty wrong..(main reason why I didn't want to post it)

By hypothesis and Deduction Theorem, $$\Gamma\vdash \lnot B\to C\land\lnot C$$ $$\implies \Gamma\vdash\lnot B\to\lnot(C\to C)$$ $$\implies\Gamma\vdash(C\to C)\to B$$

By Deduction Theorem, $\Gamma,(C\to C)\vdash B$.

As $\Gamma$ is a set of formulas, $C\to C$ might be in $\Gamma$. Therefore 
$\Gamma\vdash B.$

Comment: What is the proof you tried?  We can't see how it is wrong if you do not show the work,.

Comment: @GrahamKemp I just edited the question.

Comment: Just to clarify, isn't this known as *reductio ad absurdum* or must I stand corrected?

Comment: @user477343 I don't know. Is that english?

Comment: This is an exercise from Mendelson logic Book.

Comment: Hahah no it's not english. It's Latin. I just wanted to confirm, because I like to use latin. For instance, when I complete a proof, at the end, I would like to say *quod erat demonstradum* :)

Comment: Hint: Lemma 1.8 $\vdash_L C\to C$ if $C$ is a wff.

Comment: @GrahamKemp I don't understand how should I apply Lemma 1.8?

Comment: @Michelle You are using the hypothesis 'involves no application of Gen using a variable free in B' when you apply the deduction theorem.

Comment: @Michelle Modus Ponens. $$\begin{split}\Gamma~& \vdash ~(C\to C)\to B\\ & \vdash (C\to C) \\ \hline \Gamma ~& \vdash ~B\end{split}$$

Comment: Only a comment on you correct proof: the justification is $\vdash C \to C$, and thus we can use it in a derivation. This does not mean that it must be in $\Gamma$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proof needs some of the *derived rules* stated by Mendelson in the previous page:

1) $\Gamma, \lnot B \vdash C \land \lnot C$

2) $\Gamma, \lnot B \vdash \lnot C$ --- from 1) by Conjunction Elimination [the proof is **Ex.1.48** (d),(e) that, in turn, needs some previous result: **Lemma 1.11** (c)]

3) $\Gamma \vdash \lnot B \to \lnot C$ --- from 2) by Deduction Th: here the restriction on the use of Gen is needed

4) $\Gamma, \lnot B \vdash C$ --- from 1) by Conjunction Elimination

5) $\Gamma \vdash \lnot B \to C$ --- from 4) by Deduction Th: again, the restriction on the use of Gen is needed

6) $\vdash (\lnot B \to \lnot C) \to ((\lnot B \to C) \to B)$ --- axiom (A3)

> 7) $\Gamma \vdash B$ --- from 6), 3) and 5) by MP twice.